# Operational error while doing migration with mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-migrations

I am trying to setup a new project. It has migrations already. I created a new mysql database but while doing migrate I get error like `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table ' '  already exists")`.

Why is that error occurred inside a completely new database ?

But the default django app like admin, auth etc. migrated without an issue.

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql"
        "NAME":"mydb",
        "USER": "myuser",
        "PASSWORD": "my pwd",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT":3306,
        "OPTIONS":  {"init_command": "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"},
    }
}
```

Comment: The error shows that it thinks the table name is `' '` (a single space), which makes me think you have not specified table names correctly in your migration code. Perhaps it's using that as the table name for more than one table? You have shown only how you connect to the database, without showing your migrations. So I will just recommend you double-check that your migrations are correct.

Comment: Can you share the model as well please